# Excel/Access 2007 connectivity issues

Tags: excel, ms-access-2007, excel-2007

I am having issue on a consistent basis with some excel and access databases connected using a) Microsoft Query Wizard in Excel and b) Linked excel workbooks in Access.

Issue 1: A connection using Microsoft Query in Excel can be set up without any issues but modifying the connection a few days later becomes impossible. Even if I try to edit the SQL statement, it results in errors and never updates.

Issue 2: In Access 2007 with multiple linked workbooks and queries between them causes Access to stall and eventually crash. It all happens on a random basis and there is no specific task that it co sistently crash on, but it does crash very frequently.

Issue 3: Running a Query in Access with linked workbooks often opens the workbook in read-only mode and if another user on the server has the file open, it becomes very slow and often crashes.

A few other issues which end up slowing down the workflow or end up with a crashed application for both excel and access 2007.

I have tested the operation on another computer with office 2016 and I didn’t encounter any of the issues. I am wondering if there is an inherent issue in the Office 2007 that has been resolved in the later versions. 
Does anyone know if my assumption is correct that upgrading the office will resolve the connectivity issues between excel and access?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Issue 3 is the norm.  A linked excel to Access should not then also be opened by an excel user.

Issue 2 is a little more vague.

You don't mention the number of records/rows in these excels.  This can be key and is relevant also to the horsepower of the PC you are using.  After all this is a PC database and so the payload should be appropriate.

Access 2007 is very stable and I am surprised that 2016 is performing differently/better - and possibly if it is on a different PC - which I assume - the real reason is the power of the PC.

Having said all that - in general, it is my experience that apples-to-apples a linked excel is slower than a linked access table.  You could consider a Step 1 whereby you do a mass import/append of the excel data into an Access table(s) - and then do all your queries internally.  This will definitely perform better.

I don't do queries in excel so can't comment on Issue 1.

Hope this helps.

www.CahabaData.com